Electrochemical Cell? Metal at anode and salt at cathode
Per suggestion, complete rewrite with more details:
I no longer believe this is electrochemical migration.
There is a lot of information on:

Galvanic cells with two half-cells and a salt bridge
Electrolytic cells with applied voltage

Question:
What would happen if voltage was applied to a galvanic cell?
Problem Statement:

Assume a system contains a galvanic cell to which 425V is applied between anode and cathode.
The anode (high side) and cathode (low side) are both silver plated.
Assume the "salt bridge" is a piece of hygroscopic plastic. One of the fillers in this plastic contains sodium and/or the plastic mold release fluid contains sodium which remains as a residue on the surface.
The anode and cathode are exposed to a high temperature (410K) and high-humidity environment (85%).
Due to power cycling, there is some temperature cycling within the module containing this cell. Assume moisture condenses on the plastic surfaces around the anode and cathode and the plastic (being hygroscopic) absorbs moisture.
Results: "Silver sludge" appears at the 425V biased anode and unknown white salt containing sodium appears at the cathode.

I am assuming electrons are flowing from low side to high side (leakage current). What going on at the anode and cathode?
My hypotheses:

Electrons being "robbed" from the cathode side causing sodium, which is dissolved in condensate, to form a salt.
Silver plating is dissolved in condensate on the anode side (perhaps even some crevice corrosion). It gains an electron and is left on the surface as sludge.

Does this make sense?

The question can be improved. A lot of information is missing which might be "taken for granted" by someone who is doing the experiment on a daily basis. What is the experiment about? What is the purpose? What is the electrode composition, what is the electrolyte composition, what is the current? Is it a constant current or a constant voltage electrolysis? How far are the electrodes?

Sodium cannot be deposited at the electrode in an aqueous medium until and unless you have mercury cathode.

425 V ?? It seems like violent boiling, physical explosion due high vapor pressure, accompanied by hydrogen explosion....

Nobody will try to apply more than about 20 Volt on a galvanic cell or on any solution. With higher voltages, the situation is similar to a short circuit (and an explosion like Pouting said). The intensity will be huge and no machine can provide such a high current.
